# Hide Mini-Cart and Header-Account Dropdown When Click Outside of Those Sections

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, jquery

I am building a custom theme based on Magento 1.9 RWD.

How do I manage to hide/close the **mini cart** and **header-account** drop down by clicking anywhere outside of those sections ?

### EDIT - 1

zhartaunik's answer helped me to resolve the issue. But I am now facing below issue.

If I click the **language-switcher** its stays open. Now when I click the **mini cart** and **header-account**, those drop-downs opens, but also the **language-switcher** still stays open! I want this one to close directly when another button is clicked? How do I get this done?

Comment: Hello Meez, your first qustion is answered by zhartaunik and it helped you also. So you should reward him by accepting his answer. If you have further doubts or quiries, feel free to put a new question or contact zhartaunik for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope It has no issues...

Add this script to

> /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart/items.phtml

```
<script>
    $j('body').click(function (event)
    {
        element = $j(event.target);
        if(element.parents('.skip-link.skip-cart').length == 1 || element.hasClass('skip-cart'))
        {
            return;
        }
        var parent = $j('.minicart-wrapper').parents('.skip-content');
        var link = parent.siblings('.skip-link');

        if (element.parents('.minicart-wrapper').length == 0) {
            parent.removeClass('skip-active');
            link.removeClass('skip-active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**upd.1**

My cart is closing successfully with that extension:

[image]

Maybe you have some javascript errors in console? As you can see - my javascript is simple. If you click outside of block - it gets closed.

Comment: Ok that looks good. Thanks. And if i click first the _language switcher_ and then the _minicart_. The _language switcher_ stays open? How do i close this one automatically when clicking another link?

Comment: I have added ' || element.hasClass('skip-cart')' to if condition. Maybe now everything should work as it should

Comment: Sorry i am talking about the language-button (English, Dutch etc). This one stays open.. Its not closing when you click a link/button like 'Account' or 'Shopping card'? Do you know how to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: By which extension did you add these buttons? I can try to install it on my host and help you

Comment: I made it with [this extension](http://www.ixtendo.com/polyglot-language-switcher-2/). It's really nice and works really great to upgrade the default Magento language switcher. I adjust the code in `app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/template/page/switch/languages.phtml` to make the extension work with Magento. Thanks!

Comment: did you had any progress already? Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: sorry have no time to check it. a lot of work. update post tomorrow

Comment: updated my post

Comment: sorry, i update my question to be more clear. Hope you have a solution. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I have not enough time to help you. I think you need to make the same script for that switcher (if the click is outside switcher block - close the switcher)

Comment: I understand. hope when you have some time you can point me in the wright direction and help me a bit. Thanks